# What is the most effective way to eliminate silverfish (g. Thysanura) from walls and floorboards?

Tags: entomology, toxicology

I've had our home fumigated, but the silverfish seem to return unaffected.

Are their eggs unaffected?

What's the best way to eliminate them from your home?

Comment: This question does not appear off-topic to me. I just want to say that the question might also be a good fit on [lifehacks.SE](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com).

Comment: If you say "return", haven't they just re-populated your house?

Comment: Yes, return = re-populate.

Answer (score 2):

They feed on fungi, which grow wherever there's high humidity levels. So the best way to get rid of them would be to lower the air humidity. For example, by increasing the temperature in your (presumably) bathroom.